# how to control snake with only two keys i.e left and right

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

currently, i'm using all four keys to steer the snake left, right, up and down. I'm wondering how can i only use left and right key to move the snake around.

```
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        snake.direction = 2
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        snake.direction = 3
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        snake.direction = 0
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        snake.direction = 1
    def move(self):
        if self.direction is 0:
            self.dy = -self.block
            self.dx = 0
        if self.direction is 1:
            self.dy = self.block
            self.dx = 0
        if self.direction is 2:
            self.dy = 0
            self.dx = -self.block
        if self.direction is 3:
            self.dy = 0
            self.dx = self.block
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
```

can anyone guide me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the directions as follows:

- 0: move up
- 1: move right
- 2: move down
- 3: move right

```py
def move(self):
    if self.direction is 0:
        self.dy = -self.block
        self.dx = 0
    if self.direction is 1:
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = self.block
    if self.direction is 2:
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = -self.block
    if self.direction is 3:
        self.dy = self.block
        self.dx = 0

    self.x += self.dx
    self.y += self.dy
```

When <kbd>right</kbd> is pressed then add 1 to `snake.direction` and when <kbd>left</kbd> is pressed the subtract 1. Use the  `%` (modulo) operator (see [Binary arithmetic operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)) to ensure tha the result is in rage [0, 3]:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
    snake.direction = (snake.direction - 1) % 4
if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
    snake.direction = (snake.direction + 1) % 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    if snake.direction == 0
                        snake.direction = 2
                    elif snake.direction == 2
                        snake.direction = 1
                    elif snake.direction == 1
                        snake.direction = 3
                    elif snake.direction == 3
                        snake.direction = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    if snake.direction == 0
                        snake.direction = 3
                    elif snake.direction == 3
                        snake.direction = 1
                    elif snake.direction == 1
                        snake.direction = 2
                    elif snake.direction == 2
                        snake.direction = 0
def move(self):
    if self.direction is 0:
        self.dy = -self.block
        self.dx = 0
    if self.direction is 1:
        self.dy = self.block
        self.dx = 0
    if self.direction is 2:
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = -self.block
    if self.direction is 3:
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = self.block
    self.x += self.dx
    self.y += self.dy
```

This should rotate your snake based on the direction it was traveling before.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than set the direction based on keypress, have the left and right keys adjust the direction by adding or subtracting from the current direction.

I've also changed the `move` function so that the directions are in clockwise order.

```
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    snake.direction -= 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    snake.direction += 1

                if snake.direction > 3:
                    snake.direction = 0
                elif snake.direction < 0:
                    snake.direction = 3
def move(self):
    if self.direction is 0:
        self.dy = -self.block
        self.dx = 0
    if self.direction is 1:
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = -self.block
    if self.direction is 2:
        self.dy = self.block
        self.dx = 0
    if self.direction is 3:
        self.dy = 0
        self.dx = self.block
    self.x += self.dx
    self.y += self.dy
```